# Android App start a new one when click the icon on desktop

Tags: android, android-task

I did it like this:

Start App into an inner activity named A --> lock screen --> wait for a long time to make sure that the app has been recycled --> unlock ,show the future activity A--> press Home button --> click the app icon on desktop --> start a new App --> press back --> return to A.

I wonder how it happens?

Comment: what is the question or what is the problem that you are facing. I think u need to take a look at android activity lifecycle

Comment: @playmaker420 I mean that when I click the app icon, there should be only one program instance on the same phone, but now there are 2.It happens with the step I did in my question.I want to know how to solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

if you need solution try this

```
if (!isTaskRoot()
            && getIntent().hasCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER)
            && getIntent().getAction() != null
            && getIntent().getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_MAIN)) {

        finish();
        return;
    }
```

Here is some of the description from http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html:
**

> ... a new instance of a "singleTop" activity may also be created to
>   handle a new intent. However, if the target task already has an
>   existing instance of the activity at the top of its stack, that
>   instance will receive the new intent (in an onNewIntent() call); a new
>   instance is not created. In other circumstances — for example, if an
>   existing instance of the "singleTop" activity is in the target task,
>   but not at the top of the stack, or if it's at the top of a stack, but
>   not in the target task — a new instance would be created and pushed on
>   the stack.

**

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've thought about this method but it says that I might run this in root activity in Mainfest, however the root is a SplashActivity which will finish when start the main.

Comment: In my project, I had same problem, splash were main activity and when I wrote this method into onCreate(), problem were solved.